# Docker+Rails+Postgres: app can't access database container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

New to Docker; trying to follow along with two COdeShip tutorials for Rails+Postgres inside Docker containers. Database container starts and stops with app container under control of `docker-compose up -d` and `docker-compose rm`. Postgres commands are not available inside app container, however, so `docker-compose run app bin/rake db:create` chokes reporting that `createdb` could not be found.

I've written this up more fully in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jdickey/59cbbac9490f5ba655bf).

I've been stuck for 3 days and counting; help would be greatly appreciated!